# exporting array data from flex actionscript

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, export

I want to export the data kept in an actionscript array as a text/CSV file. I have searched and found a few that did datagrid to excel exports but they are complicated and confusing. I understand I have to create a script to handle this and I am wondering if there are examples of doing this?

I need help with:
-calling the script within actionscript code (I am not too experienced with this, can it just be something like arrayToCVS(array) ?)
-getting the "download" prompt to show up and allowing the user to save the CSV

thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should help you.  basically it takes an array, creates a number of header columns, and exports all data in the array:

```
      private function exportDataGrid(arr:Array):void{
            var exportStr:String = "";
            var delimiter:String = ",";
            var fileName:String;
            fileName = "export.txt";
            exportStr += "Title" + delimiter; 
            exportStr += "Date Created" + delimiter; 
            exportStr += "Cards" + delimiter;

            exportStr += delimiter+delimiter+delimiter+"\n";

            for each(var item:Object in arr){
                exportStr += "\""+item.title+"\""+delimiter;
                exportStr += "\""+item.dateCreated+"\""+delimiter;
                exportStr += "\""+item.numCards+"\"\n";
            }
            var fileReference:FileReference = new FileReference();
            fileReference.save(exportStr, fileName);
        }
```

Comment: Wow, thanks so much! I did not know aboutFileReference. It makes things a lot simpler :)